# Proving that block diagonal matrix is orthogonal if its entries in the main diagonal are orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Show that if  $A,B$ are two orthogonal matrix then the block matrix $$P=\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix}$$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Hint: a matrix is orthogonal iff its rows (columns) are an orthonormal basis of the corresponding space.

Comment: @DonAntonio...if $\{A_1,...A_n\}$ and $\{B_1,...B_m\}$ are the columns of $A$ and $B$ respectively How i can show that $\{A_1,...A_n, B_1,...B_m\}$ is a basis?

Comment: Take any vector $\;(x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1},...,x_{n+k})\;$ , assuming $\;P\;$ is a square matrix of order  $\;n+k\;$ . Then $\;(x_1,...,x_n)\;$ can be expressed as linear combination of the rows (columns) of $\;A\;$ ...etc. Orthonormality is almost trivial.

Comment: @DonAntonio...$\{A_1,...,A_n, B_1,...,B_m\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Luis, ¿no comprendiste mi anterior comentario?  Didn't you understand my past comment?

Comment: @LuisPrado: Since $A$ is orthogonal the columns of $A$ are orthogonal (hence linearly independent) and with unit norm. The same holds for $B$. It follows that the columns of $P$ are orthogonal (hence linearly independent) and with unit norm, so $P$ is orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Note that $$ {}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}P=\begin{pmatrix} {}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}A & 0 \\\ 0 & {}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}B \end{pmatrix}$$
and use product by blocks.

Comment: +1, seems like the clearest way to think about it. Is there any reason you write $t$ on the left? I've never seen that.

Comment: That's the standard way I learnt it when I was a student, with a prescript roman t. May be it's old style notation.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let

$A:V \to V$ and $B:W \to W$. The corresponding block diagonal matrix is exactly
$(A \oplus B):V \oplus W  \to V \oplus W$.

Hence, we have that the transpose is the matrix representation of the dual, so

$$\mathrm{Hom}(V \oplus W,k) =(V \oplus W)^* \cong(V^* \oplus W^*)$$
where the last isomorphism is the standard one used for $\mathrm{Hom}$, induced by restriction, so they have the same matrix representation. Hence,

$I_{V \oplus W}=I \oplus I=(AA^*) \oplus (BB)^*=(A \oplus B) \circ(A^* \oplus B^*) =(A \oplus B) \circ(A \oplus B)^*$

Comment: There are already two good answers  (one in the comments and one by Bernard) so I feel justified in sharing how I thought about it, although it may be a bit hand wavy.

Comment: Also, I'll note that this answer is more or less the same as Bernard's, I just didnt' know about that fact, but this is one way to guess it!